# Carry across multiple capture groups in array but match only one group

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to make a simple modification to some existing code without much luck, i want to carry across one more capture group from FILE1: $2, before comparing $1 as usual with data in FILE2 and printing both if a successful match occurs. Please keep the answer similar to my attempt if possible, so i am able to understand the changes.

FILE1 data:

```
abc 99269 +t
abc 550 -a
abc 100 +a
gdh 126477 +t 
hduf 1700 +c
```

FILE2 data:

```
517 1878 forward
2156 3289 forward
99000 100000 forward
22000 23000 backward
999555 999999 backward
```

Desired output:

```
99269 +t 99000 100000 forward
550 -a 517 1878 forward
1700 +c 517 1878 forward
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $outputfile = "/Users/edwardtickle/Documents/CC22CDSpositive.txt"; 

open FILE1, "/Users/edwardtickle/Documents/CC22indelscc.txt";

open FILE2, "/Users/edwardtickle/Documents/CDS_rmmge.CC22.CORE.aln";

open (OUTPUTFILE, ">$outputfile");
my @file1list=();
my @indels=();

while (<FILE1>) {
    if (/^\S+\s+(\d+)\s+(\S+)/) {
        push @file1list, $1;
        push @indels, $2;
    }
}

close FILE1;

while ( my $line = <FILE2> ) {
    if ($line =~ /^>\S+\s+\S+\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\S+)/) {
        my $cds1 = $1;
        my $cds2 = $2;
        my $cds3 = $3;

        for my $cc22 (@file1list) {
            for my $indel (@indels) {
                if ( $cc22 > $cds1 && $cc22 < $cds2 ) {
                    print OUTPUTFILE "$cc22 $indel $cds1 $cds2 $cds3\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

close FILE2;
close OUTPUTFILE;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's frustrating that you don't seem to be learning from the many solutions and pieces of advice you've been given.

Here's a program that will do as you ask.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

chdir '/Users/edwardtickle/Documents';

open my $fh, '<', 'CDS_rmmge.CC22.CORE.aln';

my @file2;
while (<$fh>) {
  next unless /\S/;
  push @file2, [ split ];
}

open my $out, '>', 'CC22CDSpositive.txt';

open $fh, '<', 'CC22indelscc.txt';

while (<$fh>) {

  my @line1 = split;

  for my $line2 (@file2) {

    if ( $line1[1] >= $line2->[0] and $line1[1] <= $line2->[1] ) {
      my @out = ( @line1[1,2], @$line2 );
      print $out "@out\n";
      last;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I do think i am learning, that is why i ask that people try to keep the script as similar to my attempt as possible. I have written many successful pieces of code independent of the forum and i only ask when i am completely stuck. For someone who had never even heard of perl a month ago your comment isn't a very helpful thing to say, but as always i appreciate your help.

Comment: @EdTickle: If you insist on holding on to the side of the pool, you will never learn to swim. For instance I think I've changed your awkward regular expressions to a simple `split` more than once before, and I am sure you have been advised to use lexical file handles, but you have stuck to your old ways. If you spare half an hour or so to understand what I have written then it will set you up much better to progress with good Perl habits. I am more than happy to explain any parts that baffle you, but if you don't even give it a chance then you will never know.

Comment: I was using regexs simply due to advice from my project supervisor, but i've just looked into the split function and now understand your code, cheers. I'll now try to apply it to a much harder problem instead of using regex but will undoubtable be back for help.

Comment: @EdTickle: I'm glad that you understand it. The most arcane part is the use of array *references*. The first `for` loop reads the whole of the `.aln` file into array of arrays `@file2`, and Perl implements such things as an array of array *references*. Later on, scalar `$line2` is set to each of those references, and the syntax for accessing array elements through a reference is `$line2->[0]` etc. It's also worth pointing out that the default behaviour of `split` is `split ' ', $_` which is subtly different from `split / /, $_` or `split /\s+/, $_` and is usually what you want.

Comment: @EdTickle: As I said, I am more than happy to explain anything I write, but please remember that Stack Overflow is a universal resource and not just a chance to get help for your own particular problem. It would be very wrong of me to submit something less than optimal just to take into account any one personal preference.